# Having trouble understanding sink current values for an LM74700-Q1 ideal diode controller

Tags: datasheet, reverse-polarity

This is my first time referring/understanding a datasheet.
As I understand it from a quick search,  a sink current is the current (negative) which flows into a port, while source current is the current which flows out of the port.

When I try to relate this definition with the corresponding values for [LM74700](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm74700-q1.pdf) IC, I just don't get the relation.

[image]

Such as the one listed above I<sub>(EN)</sub>. Does this mean current flowing into the EN pin of the IC? This doesn't make sense to me but as per the definition it should. If so, why isn't it negative?

Similarly for I<sub>(GATE)</sub>:

[image]

For reference, here is the block diagram of the IC:

[image]

Edit -> Application Schematic:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sink current is current INTO the pin.  The reason they don't use negative units is because sink/source is your indicator of direction.

Had they used negative units for the sink current, it might be confusing because it is implying current going the other way.

Comment: Okay, gotcha! Another thing, this might be incorrect(blatantly) but I wanted to know whether I can relate the anode and cathode voltages which have been cited multiple times in the datasheet (working parameter) as the Source and Drain voltages of an NMOS as seen in the application schematic(see the main post included as an edit) as I feel like I can better understand it that way. I have a hard time imaging Potential differences within an IC. (newbie + not much of hands-on experience with such devices)

Comment: @Harkirat Yes, that is exactly how those relate, and is a good way to think about it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go over the datasheet again with this approach, ought to clear up some of my other doubts. I'll follow through with the typical characteristics. Just this last doubt ;-; So I know I'm not designing any circuit right now and in my opinion all the given specs aren't really relevant while designing or incorporating this IC into a circuit(maybe wrong). In real world use could you point out what params are to be taken care of / looked at carefully?

Comment: @Harkirat Please make that a separate question.

Comment: Sure thing, thanks for the help! Much appreciated.